# Unity Trigger Collision not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I'm currently working on a simple race game in Unity3D. The player is a racecar, racing against an AI that uses waypoints to navigate across the map. Everytime the player crosses the finish line, a lapcounter adds one lap. I want the same to happen to the AI lapcounter, but as soon as the AI crosses the finish line, nothing happens. Not even the Debug.Log shows anything happening. I have a tinyurl with the project [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02372151143969578691).

Below you'll find the code that's used to trigger the lapcounter.

Any help is appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StartTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public Light StartFlash;
    public int lapcount=0;
    public int AIlapcount=0;
    public int ctimer=10;
    public int AIctimer=10;
    public float gametime;
    public float timedisp;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartFlash.intensity =0;
        gametime = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        gametime+=Time.deltaTime;
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter( Collider MyTrigger){
        if ((MyTrigger.gameObject.tag == "Buggy") && (lapcount == 0)) {
            Debug.Log ("Trigger passed");
            lapcount = 1;
            ctimer = 10;
        }
        ctimer -= 2;

        if ((MyTrigger.gameObject.tag == "Buggy") && (lapcount == 1) && (ctimer <= 0)) {
            lapcount = 2;
            ctimer = 10;
        }
        ctimer -= 2;

        if ((MyTrigger.gameObject.tag == "Buggy") && (lapcount == 2) && (ctimer <= 0)) {
            lapcount = 3;
            ctimer = 10;
        }
        if ((MyTrigger.gameObject.tag == "Buggy") && (lapcount == 3) && (ctimer <= 0)) {
            Application.LoadLevel (0);
        }
    }

    void AITriggerEnter( Collider Trigger){
        Debug.Log ("AI Trigger passed");
        if ((Trigger.gameObject.tag == "AIBuggy") && (AIlapcount ==0)) {
            AIlapcount =1;
            AIctimer=10;
        }
        AIctimer-=2;

        if((Trigger.gameObject.tag == "AIBuggy") && (AIlapcount == 1) && (AIctimer <= 0)) {
            AIlapcount =2;
            AIctimer=10;
        }
        AIctimer-=2;

        if((Trigger.gameObject.tag == "AIBuggy") && (AIlapcount == 2) && (AIctimer <= 0)) {
            AIlapcount =3;
            AIctimer=10;
        }
        if((Trigger.gameObject.tag == "AIBuggy") && (AIlapcount == 3) && (AIctimer <= 0)) {
            Application.LoadLevel(0);
        }


    } // end OnTriggerEnter

    void OnGUI(){

        //PlayerCarScript myCar = mPlayer.GetComponent <PlayerCarScript> ();

        GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (10, 10, 200, 140));

            GUI.Box (new Rect (0, 0, 200, 110), "User Interface");

            GUI.TextField (new Rect (0, 30, 100, 25), "Laps: " + lapcount);
            GUI.TextField (new Rect (0, 55, 100, 25), "Game Time: " + gametime.ToString("f1"));
            GUI.TextField (new Rect (0, 80, 100, 25), "Timer: " + ctimer);

        GUI.EndGroup ();

        GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (600, 10, 200, 140));

        GUI.Box (new Rect (0, 0, 200, 110), "Opponent Interface");

        GUI.TextField (new Rect (0, 30, 100, 25), "Laps: " + AIlapcount);
        //GUI.TextField (new Rect (0, 55, 100, 25), "Game Time: " + gametime.ToString("f1"));
        GUI.TextField (new Rect (0, 80, 100, 25), "Timer: " + AIctimer);

        GUI.EndGroup ();
    }

    void Flash(){

        StartFlash.intensity = 8 - StartFlash.intensity;

    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen this countless times. Info I need from you to solve it: Colliders, Rigibodies, and AI code.

Comment: Is the IsTrigger option in the triggers checked? Do the objects have rigid bodies?

Comment: IsTrigger is checked, both race cars have rigid bodies. if you press the  ''here'' in my previous post you can get all the files you'll need to see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure then `AITriggerEnter` would ever be called.

`OnTriggerEnter` will be called when a rigidbody with a collider enters a collider with a `isTrigger` set to true.

Instead of having two method, add all the logic inside `OnTriggerEnter`, or at least make sure that methods are called from there, e.g.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    bool isPlayer = other.compareTag("Buggy");
    bool isAI = other.compareTag("AIBuggy");
    if (!isPlayer && !isAI) return;
    
    if (isPlayer) {
        lapcount++;
    }
    else if (isPlayer) {
        AIlapcount++;
    }
}
```

Not sure what the timer is for, but this seems like a much simpler version of what you're going for